# How does oauth work in ionic2?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, angular, ionic2

Haven't found any decent information on how to implement oauth in ionic2.

Im still fairly new to ionic2 so any resources, libraries or code samples would be highly appreciated!

EDIT: Added app example created in ionic2. Currently the best way to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the best way to learn ionic2 is through examples.

[This complete conference app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app) gives a good overview.

Recommend you to check it out if you want to learn ionic2.